# MVVMLight Message Bus single sync/async

Tags: mvvm, messaging

The **MVVMLight** for the **Silverlight** application has a Message Bus. The View Models can send messages between each other so all of them can be decoupled. My question is, is Sending message an sync or async operation?

In the following code, the Main (Coordinating) View Model sends messages to all the child VMs to load data. After all the data is loaded, the Main VM has to display a status saying all data is loaded which is set in the variable **IsAllChildViewModelsCompletedLoading**
.

```
MainVM.PopulateData()
{
    IsAllChildViewModelsCompletedLoading = false; // Line 1

    MessageBus.Send(new Child1VMMessage()); // Line 2
    MessageBus.Send(new Child2VMMessage()); // Line 3
    MessageBus.Send(new Child3VMMessage()); // Line 4

    IsAllChildViewModelsCompletedLoading = true; // Line 5
}
```

In the above code, does the **MessageBus.Send** on the 3 line wait until the 2 **MessageBus.Send** is completed. Does the code on line 5 is executed only after the code on 2,3,4 are executed? Or the **PopulateData** method will exit faster by setting the flag **IsAllChildViewModelsCompletedLoading** to true and there is no way we can know all the child VM are done loading by using the above method?

Answer (score 2):

After doing some debugging I came to the conclusion that they are synchronous and not run in different threads, so it is safe to call the line 5.

Answer (score 2):

As per this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn745866.aspx) by Laurent Bugnion, the messenger operations are synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

True but...

You could use async method in the listener when processing the message.
Or in the message callback too.

Comment: Using three async operations will also be run asynchronously, so setting IsAllChildViewModelsCompletedLoading to true is safe. Converting all the three operations to tasks has the advantage of running them parallel.